# RVM : Unrecognized option: --prefix when installing RVM on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, rvm

so I was following a guide to install ruby and ROR 3, when I came to
the command:

```
bash < <( curl https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

When I run this command, get the following output:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/.git/
>
> remote: Counting objects: 5929, done.
>
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2846/2846), done.
>
> remote: Total 5929 (delta 3892), reused 4168 (delta 2316)
>
> Receiving objects: 100% (5929/5929), 1.96 MiB | 780 KiB/s, done.
>
> Resolving deltas: 100% (3892/3892), done.
>
> Unrecognized option: --prefix,

with the offending line being the "Unrecognized option: --prefix"

I'm not sure how to resolve this, but the install breaks at that line. I've tried removing the git directory and reinstalling to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, it appears you're using an older version of the RVM installer, the current command (as per [RVM's site](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)) is:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer
```